# Map Angular HttpClient error with its type

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I want to map HttpClient's error with its type and I have this code:

```js
export class ErrorMessageInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private notifyService: NotifyService) {}

  public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        console.error(error);
        return throwError({
          ok: error.ok,
          status: error.status,
          statusText: error.statusText,
          code: error.error.error.code,
          message: error.error.error.message,
          headers: error.headers,
          url: error.url,
        } as OdataError);
      }),
      tap(() => {}, async error => {
        await this.notifyService.error(error.message);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

But unfortunately the default type for `error` in `tap` operator remains `any` and I'd not want to map the error type wherever it'll be used. So I have 2 questions here:

1. Why the mapped type error is not visible in the code above?
2. Is there a way to set custom error type globally or at least for injected `HttpClient`'s instance?

Comment: Regarding 1. The parameter of the `error` callback is always defined as `any`. It's not typed like the `next` callback. See: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/tap.ts

Comment: Thanks for finding that, @fridoo. I guess it also answers my second question that such mapping is not possible yet. At least not without forking RxJS...

Comment: "(error: HttpErrorResponse)" - it would just work. for "message" - you would need to create some kind of mapper(cause it is not the same with initial HttpErrorResponse); https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse

Comment: update: in "tap" - "async (error: OdataError)" should work

Comment: Sure, it will work for the single function, but what I'm doing here is looking for a way to do it globally